# How to integrate Gnosis chain to react native

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

In React native, I am trying to create a small wallet app for Gnosis Chain. I want the Dapp to show the balance of xDai and allow for sending and receiving as well. Any ideas on where to start for this kind of implementation?

Comment: The same way and tools as you do it for ethereum oder bsc

Comment: or* instead of „oder“